# Can you update file access permission for data file within my own app folder on iPhone

Tags: ios, security, file, system

I am wondering if there is way to programmatically change the permission on a file in my app folder on iPad. For example, I wanted to add group write permission to my own file in the Frameworks folder in my App. Can this be done somehow? Note, this is not a jailbroken device. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot change files in application container (folder).

Comment: To add on to this: any change to the contents of your app's bundle will invalidate its signature, and the OS will refuse to run the app.